# Creating browser site history in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and I'd like to build a panel to show Recently Viewed URLs within my web site.
I'm trying to use the `createBrowserHistory` library to do that from a navigation page. Here is the layout:

```
└── navigation
    ├── component1
    └── component2
    └── component3
```

I'd like to implement something where if I click on component3, then component1, then component2, it would display something like this:

Recently Visited:
component2
component1
component3

I have a `History.js` file that consists of only this:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory({
  })
```

and from the `Navigation.js` page, I have something like this:

```js
import history from './path/to/History';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const location = useLocation();
history.push(location)
```

Now if I do a `console.log(history)`, I just see the current path that I'm on, but not the previous URLs. I was under the impression that `history.push()` pushes the URL to a stack, but how do I extract the last several URLs that were visited?

Answer (score 1):

[You need to add the history as a property into the Router(router provider)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Router.md#router)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

And then your hooks would be work well as your expected

Comment: My ReactDOM.render uses BrowserRouter -- how would it work with that? The history parameter doesn't seem to do anything and I saw from a few other posts that BrowserRouter maintains its own history. I'm a little confused on how it would then be accessible.

Comment: Did you upgrade router-dom

Comment: [It can be injected](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js)

Comment: In other hand, how about just use `location` by `useLocation`. try to log `location` and push by `history` from `useHistory`. I think it can fit what you want. Because I've view the source code. The history object created by `createBrowserHistory` already used by `BrowserRouter`. So you can easily get history by `useHostory`

Comment: I did this
```
let siteHistory = useHistory();
siteHistory.push(location.pathname, true)
console.log(siteHistory.location.pathname)
```
and I just see the current path. Do I need to capture this in a state somewhere?

Comment: Are you using chrome? try to log history or location. And then take a look what the data structure they are. Logs in chrome dev console would be an object node tree  that can make you easy to understand how to get what you need. Just try to find out the data you need.

Comment: Yeah, no I get that. I can see it in the console window in Chrome when I do a console.log.
I am currently doing this:
const location = useLocation();
const [locations, setLocations] = useState([])

setLocations(locations.concat(location.pathname))

Hopefully that will be the right way to keep the history in a state.